# Select Datagrid Rows with Checkbox

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, checkbox, devexpress

I'm using visual studio 2008 .net 3.5 (windows application)
I have a Devexpress datagridview and I want to select multiple rows using checkboxes . I have found this Code in Devexpress Forum.( http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/E1271.aspx )
it works very good , but I dont know how to recognize which rows are selected !

I want user select some rows with checkboxes and then copy the selected rows to another datagrid. 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for:

```
yourDataGridView.SelectedRows
```

which returns a DataGridViewSelectedRow collection. You can iterate it through a foreach loop, like:

```
foreach (selectedDataGridViewRow row in yourDataGridView.SelectedRows)
{
    // do what you got to do with the selected row...
}
```

Comment: Please expand your question to show what you have attempted and where/why you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the code sample from DevExpress there's the member *selection* that stores the selected rows. The following two parts of the sample seem to approve that:

```
protected ArrayList selection;

//...

void SelectRow(int rowHandle, bool select, bool invalidate) {
    if (IsRowSelected(rowHandle) == select) return;
    object row = _view.GetRow(rowHandle);
    if (select)
        selection.Add(row);
    else
        selection.Remove(row);
    if (invalidate) {
       Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Have a look at this member, I think that's what you are searching.